# Field initializer is in constructor in IL, but not when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, object-initializers, intermediate-language

In IL code,the field initialization is in constructor.

[Field initialization in Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOpQC.png)

But in VS2017 debug ,the field initialization is not in constructor, but in class.

[Field initialization in VS Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfLPV.png)

Source Code:

```
class A
{
    public int id = 0;
    public A()
    {
        id = 99;
    }
}

class B:A
{
    string name = "11";
    public B()
    {
        name = "22";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you show the generated IL? Or the relevent part of it?

Comment: Not totally sure why this question is getting down votes, as its a good question to the uninitiated, has all the relevant code, and has a good answer

Comment: It is expected the VS debugger shows the original code you write, and it is just that the Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler tries to be smart to rewrite the code for you (for better performance or whatever reasons the compiler writers know) - so the generated IL can be quite different from your original.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad as mentioned above,it has the iL Code

Comment: @kennyzx ohho,maybe u r correct.thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look like a problem. The compiler moves field initializations into the constructor, but the debug information tries to follow the C# code as closely as possible.

So actually your IL will look something like this:

```
class B:A
{
    string name;

    public B()
    {
        // hidden from debugger
        name = "11"

        // here's where the debugger is told the constructor starts
        name = "22";
    }
}
```

That's why your breakpoint on `public B()` shows that `name` is already initialized.

Comment: ,thx your answer.But why the debug information do this that follows the C# code as closely as possible?

Comment: To allow for a better debugging experience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your debugger's arrow (the yellow one, idk what's the name) until it past the

```
name = "22";
```